# wordpress fixing image aspect ratio

Tags: wordpress, image, aspect-ratio

I am trying to set the aspect ratio for a front page image that is almost full width. Currently as the screen gets smaller it decreases in width faster than height and looks skewed as a result.

I was thinking to use a media query to set brake points but that would mean some skewing inbetween the break points so I would prefer to use something that locks the height to the width and therefore keeps the aspect ratio. Can someone tell me how to do this in wordpress?

site(http://www.taranoone.ie/)

Comment: have u tried https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail ?

Comment: Thanks for those links, I had a look. I dont understand php so I was hoping that there would be a CSS solution I could implement using the 'Custom CSS plugin'. 

The image I want to change is the almost fullwidth on the front page (http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Counselling-room-Arklow1-1024x384.jpg).

Could you tell me if there is a CSS solution to lock the aspect ratio?